# Restrict list for table - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to limit the number of rows in the table, because I get about 40 rows from the API, and I need to make 5 rows. Tell me, what method should be applied in `List.generate` to show only the first 5 elements from the list? Thanks in advance.

**DataTable**

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<BlockModel>>(
              future: futureBlock,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return DataTable(
                      columns: const [
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Height')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Hash')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Time')),
                      ],
                      rows: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) {
                        return DataRow(cells: [
                          DataCell(Text('${snapshot.data![index].height}')),
                          DataCell(Text(snapshot.data![index].hash)),
                          DataCell(Text('${snapshot.data![index].time}')),
                        ]);
                      })
                      );
                } else {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `List.generate` is the length. You currently wrote `snapshot.data!.length`, if you want the first 5, just put `5` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can [restrict the length](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) of the List while generating it.

```
rows: List.generate(5, (index) {

// ---Your Code---

}
```

Here you can see instead of `snapshot.data!.length` you can pass the predefined length. Please apply the logic yourself if the `snapshot.data.length` is lesser than five

Comment: Really, my carelessness. Thanks a lot for your help)